# Можно ли сделать чтобы у пользователя были права админа над ботом в телеграме

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Можно ли реализовать права админа внутри бота. То есть будет бот, у которого есть подписчики в виде работников, которые выбирают свой специалитет и эта инфа идет в бд, но при этом чтобы был один админ, который мог написать боту сообщение(заранее выбрав специальность) и при этом данное сообщение доставлялось от имени бота конкретно тем людям, специальность которых выбрал админ

Comment: да, можно такое сделать. читайте документацию телеграмм апи

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается довольно легко, я думаю Вы уже использовали следующий метод при отправке сообщений: `message.chat.id`. Вы должны записать id людей, которые должны быть админами себе в отдельный файл, и потом обращаться и при запуске проверять входит ли текущий id в список id админов

Answer (score 0):

если вы говорите про отправку сообщений от одного лица, я думаю можно попробовать сделать хандлер или register_next_step_handler. который принимает текст сообщения и проверять статус пользователя с помощью двух команд

```
member = bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
print(memb.status)
```

как можно увидеть, статус или же "должность" пользователя определяет метод status, ф дальше, методом функций и созданием переменных, которые высчитывают количество администраторов и условиям можно решить вашу проблему, либо использовать выше приведенные мной две строки кода, но проверять статус на "creator", то-есть

```
if memb.status == "creator":
```

прописывайте условие

только здесь будут проверяться не администраторы, а создатели, но создатель группы только один.